# tail -F on a symlink that gets updated

Tags: shell, redhat, tail

Could someone please help me understand the below behavior ?

Let's say there are 2 dirs each one with 1 file inside :

```
aaa/file1
bbb/file2
```

And then there's a symlink pointing to file1, e.g. :

```
current -> aaa/file1
```

From 2 separate sessions I push some data into the 2 files. In one I push random numbers and in the other some constant text :

```
while true;do echo $RANDOM >> aaa/file1 ; sleep 8; done
```

and

```
while true; do echo HELLO >> bbb/file2 ; sleep 8; done
```

I then run `tail -F` on the symlink using the `---disable-inotify` as a workaround for [this bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2011-08/msg00041.html) and I see the random values as expected :

```
tail -F ---disable-inotify current
53
27169
30599
...
```

From another session I then update the symlink and make it point to the other file instead :

```
ln -sf bbb/file2 current
```

As expected, after that the `tail` output has switched to :

```
tail: ‘current’ has been replaced;  following end of new file
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
...
```

But now after I switch back again the symlink to point to the 1st file :

```
ln -sf aaa/file1 current
```

The tail output remains on HELLO, i.e. **still following the previous file bbb/file2** :

```
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
```

Does anyone knows why this happens ? Is this still related to the previously mentioned bug or I am missing something else here ?
(I'm on RHEL 7.2 // GNU coreutils 8.22)

Comment: Memory says the symlink has followed the name of the symlink. You might also need option `-n`. To explore further, I find `ls -l` is very useful.

Comment: On Mint 19, coreutils 8.28, tail will 'flip' back to aaa/file1